# WebDriver resize new windows

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Whenever I open a new window by clicking on a target="_blank" anchor using WebDriver, the window size seems to be undefined. This is usually no problem in browsers that open new windows in tabs, but it becomes a problem in e.g. PhantomJS.

Setting the size explicitly is no problem, but IMHO it's dirty to do this in Page Object classes explicitly.
What I'd like is to either set a default window size OR trigger some event code whenever a new window is opened.

Comment: Java. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I found new tabs/windows to be a problem itself in Selenium test automation. Here you can find description how to bypass it, rather than deal with consequences:

http://automatictester.co.uk/2013/08/03/chromedriver-problem-with-opening-a-new-browser-tab/

Comment: I use that for some tests already. However, some of our tests require multiple windows. Switching between them and resizing explicitly is no problem. I'd only like to do it implicitly so that I don't have to do resizing in page objects.